# Why position:sticky is not working when the element is wrapped inside another one?

Tags: html, css, sticky

I am experimenting with sticky nav and I ran into problem. Problem is that when I put the nav in other element it's not anymore sticky.

```css
.nav-wrapper{
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0;
}

.nav-wrapper nav{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
     <nav>
      <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
     </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: I believe (but don't know for sure) the question was being downvoted because it lacked code before your revision 4 minutes ago.

Comment: but i believe that this problem can be solved without code by person that knows css well :)

Comment: There is no problem that can be solved without code ... the problem arised from a particular code that's what we need to see a code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`position:sticky` consider the parent element to behave as it should be. In your case the parent element has its height defined by the sticky element so there is no room for the element to have a sticky behavior

Add border to better see the issue:

```css
.nav-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.nav-wrapper nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

body {
  min-height:200vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">
      <li>Home</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>About</li>
    </a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Now add height to the parent element and see what is happening:

```css
.nav-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 2px solid;
  height:80vh;
}

.nav-wrapper nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

body {
  min-height:200vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">
      <li>Home</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>About</li>
    </a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

The sticky behavior is working fine because there is enough height on the parent element where the element can be fixed after a specific threshold.

> A stickily positioned element is an element whose computed position
> value is sticky. It's treated as relatively positioned **until its**
> **containing block crosses a specified threshold** (such as setting top to
> value other than auto) within its flow root (or the container it
> scrolls within), at which point it is treated as "stuck" **until meeting**
> **the opposite edge of its containing block**.<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)</sup>

Related questions:

[Why bottom:0 doesn't work with position:sticky?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54609208/8620333)

[If you specify `bottom: 0` for position: sticky, why is it doing something different from the specs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55965662/8620333)

['position: sticky' not working when 'height' is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49848196/8620333)

Comment: Is there any other way to use this sticky behaviour without giving room?

Answer (score -1):

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
}

.side-bar {
  width: 250px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.content-box {
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="side-bar">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content-box">
      <!-- Link conent-->
      <div id="link1">
        <h1>Link One</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis,
          sequi voluptates ratione iure quidem cum tempora! Voluptate
          consequatur numquam assumenda natus eum quisquam non repudiandae
          corrupti, dignissimos omnis enim voluptatem, exercitationem
          incidunt beatae. Dignissimos eius maxime ullam rem praesentium
          iusto natus cum corporis rerum, voluptates recusandae ea
          repudiandae dicta autem ex! Repellat iusto, sit ratione suscipit
          quidem reiciendis, similique laboriosam nemo, ipsa sint sapiente
          amet itaque enim aliquam eligendi molestias tenetur at adipisci?
          Sint, blanditiis. Molestiae nobis, quam sequi sapiente id
          voluptate corrupti commodi voluptas alias distinctio nam sunt
          ipsam ad non ratione exercitationem, nihil deleniti maiores velit
          labore quibusdam reprehenderit impedit deserunt! Reiciendis nemo
          ducimus fugiat perferendis esse ut accusantium officiis, neque
          minima voluptates ipsum corrupti, quo ratione rem tempora?
          Laudantium, quidem? Dolor laudantium fuga nihil odit, autem
          asperiores iste explicabo. Officia rerum ab facilis odio explicabo
          minima maiores distinctio a cumque, mollitia beatae sunt ullam
          soluta et exercitationem est quae. Fugiat cum veniam nostrum,
          ullam laudantium porro debitis reprehenderit natus, consectetur
          qui neque labore maxime. Obcaecati repudiandae, ab cupiditate
          deleniti repellat commodi id ullam, dignissimos quidem, fugiat
          saepe dolor distinctio odit recusandae accusantium nemo. Fugit
          dolorem quibusdam laboriosam? Alias voluptatem corporis quos. Sint
          quod eos, dignissimos, tempore similique repudiandae deserunt aut
          voluptate quis nulla sequi quam fugiat impedit? Laudantium fugiat
          magnam earum amet, accusantium nostrum veritatis eum, et minima ut
          cupiditate molestias totam corporis sit suscipit cumque?
          Repudiandae commodi officia minima, nesciunt ex labore veniam quos
          libero eum porro et quibusdam facere esse earum debitis culpa
          quisquam eius quia quae eligendi? Libero, ullam esse quas quisquam
          at et provident officia similique iste porro nisi aliquid, dolor
          delectus velit. Corporis, eum corrupti. Aspernatur perspiciatis
          sed inventore vitae fugiat deleniti vero exercitationem ut ex
          assumenda nulla porro unde aperiam, ullam ipsum in non tempore
          repudiandae harum quasi dolorum. Quas sint ab voluptatum,
          praesentium, neque reiciendis voluptas quae quisquam aperiam
          quibusdam, illum iusto quo et impedit porro tenetur animi sapiente
          eligendi ipsam ad voluptate! Nesciunt quas sunt molestiae
          laboriosam? Natus quo at a officia cupiditate autem, numquam
          sapiente maxime fugiat beatae quis amet voluptates. Facere ducimus
          natus magni ipsa numquam nobis laborum quisquam itaque assumenda
          quaerat commodi vel vero dolores, accusantium, adipisci quasi
          iusto quis consectetur, eligendi asperiores inventore distinctio.
          Ut officiis molestiae dolorum, recusandae doloremque accusantium
          dignissimos atque ad omnis. Ex perspiciatis, commodi labore veniam
          eos a exercitationem deleniti eaque in quaerat corrupti atque
          tenetur voluptate, sint libero quo? Alias pariatur itaque eligendi
          voluptas tenetur, nobis eveniet, ex dolorem modi consequatur
          dolore recusandae nostrum! Alias numquam nemo perspiciatis libero,
          blanditiis in aliquid placeat quia velit iste repudiandae rem
          laborum ratione molestiae quas beatae, nulla, suscipit quos
          commodi at deleniti vel incidunt distinctio recusandae! Fugit
          voluptatum officiis mollitia necessitatibus aperiam temporibus est
          dolores atque inventore minus quam unde ipsum alias sapiente sint
          dolorem ullam, placeat commodi adipisci maxime suscipit odio
          reiciendis labore quasi. Architecto vero repudiandae voluptatum
          vel temporibus, ea omnis sapiente. Ut, eligendi doloribus error
          ullam obcaecati sint sequi. Ipsa debitis doloribus nulla soluta!
          Distinctio sed placeat eos blanditiis delectus.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- Link conent-->

      <!-- Link conent-->
      <div id="link2">
        <h1>Link Two</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis,
          sequi voluptates ratione iure quidem cum tempora! Voluptate
          consequatur numquam assumenda natus eum quisquam non repudiandae
          corrupti, dignissimos omnis enim voluptatem, exercitationem
          incidunt beatae. Dignissimos eius maxime ullam rem praesentium
          iusto natus cum corporis rerum, voluptates recusandae ea
          repudiandae dicta autem ex! Repellat iusto, sit ratione suscipit
          quidem reiciendis, similique laboriosam nemo, ipsa sint sapiente
          amet itaque enim aliquam eligendi molestias tenetur at adipisci?
          Sint, blanditiis. Molestiae nobis, quam sequi sapiente id
          voluptate corrupti commodi voluptas alias distinctio nam sunt
          ipsam ad non ratione exercitationem, nihil deleniti maiores velit
          labore quibusdam reprehenderit impedit deserunt! Reiciendis nemo
          ducimus fugiat perferendis esse ut accusantium officiis, neque
          minima voluptates ipsum corrupti, quo ratione rem tempora?
          Laudantium, quidem? Dolor laudantium fuga nihil odit, autem
          asperiores iste explicabo. Officia rerum ab facilis odio explicabo
          minima maiores distinctio a cumque, mollitia beatae sunt ullam
          soluta et exercitationem est quae. Fugiat cum veniam nostrum,
          ullam laudantium porro debitis reprehenderit natus, consectetur
          qui neque labore maxime. Obcaecati repudiandae, ab cupiditate
          deleniti repellat commodi id ullam, dignissimos quidem, fugiat
          saepe dolor distinctio odit recusandae accusantium nemo. Fugit
          dolorem quibusdam laboriosam? Alias voluptatem corporis quos. Sint
          quod eos, dignissimos, tempore similique repudiandae deserunt aut
          voluptate quis nulla sequi quam fugiat impedit? Laudantium fugiat
          magnam earum amet, accusantium nostrum veritatis eum, et minima ut
          cupiditate molestias totam corporis sit suscipit cumque?
          Repudiandae commodi officia minima, nesciunt ex labore veniam quos
          libero eum porro et quibusdam facere esse earum debitis culpa
          quisquam eius quia quae eligendi? Libero, ullam esse quas quisquam
          at et provident officia similique iste porro nisi aliquid, dolor
          delectus velit. Corporis, eum corrupti. Aspernatur perspiciatis
          sed inventore vitae fugiat deleniti vero exercitationem ut ex
          assumenda nulla porro unde aperiam, ullam ipsum in non tempore
          repudiandae harum quasi dolorum. Quas sint ab voluptatum,
          praesentium, neque reiciendis voluptas quae quisquam aperiam
          quibusdam, illum iusto quo et impedit porro tenetur animi sapiente
          eligendi ipsam ad voluptate! Nesciunt quas sunt molestiae
          laboriosam? Natus quo at a officia cupiditate autem, numquam
          sapiente maxime fugiat beatae quis amet voluptates. Facere ducimus
          natus magni ipsa numquam nobis laborum quisquam itaque assumenda
          quaerat commodi vel vero dolores, accusantium, adipisci quasi
          iusto quis consectetur, eligendi asperiores inventore distinctio.
          Ut officiis molestiae dolorum, recusandae doloremque accusantium
          dignissimos atque ad omnis. Ex perspiciatis, commodi labore veniam
          eos a exercitationem deleniti eaque in quaerat corrupti atque
          tenetur voluptate, sint libero quo? Alias pariatur itaque eligendi
          voluptas tenetur, nobis eveniet, ex dolorem modi consequatur
          dolore recusandae nostrum! Alias numquam nemo perspiciatis libero,
          blanditiis in aliquid placeat quia velit iste repudiandae rem
          laborum ratione molestiae quas beatae, nulla, suscipit quos
          commodi at deleniti vel incidunt distinctio recusandae! Fugit
          voluptatum officiis mollitia necessitatibus aperiam temporibus est
          dolores atque inventore minus quam unde ipsum alias sapiente sint
          dolorem ullam, placeat commodi adipisci maxime suscipit odio
          reiciendis labore quasi. Architecto vero repudiandae voluptatum
          vel temporibus, ea omnis sapiente. Ut, eligendi doloribus error
          ullam obcaecati sint sequi. Ipsa debitis doloribus nulla soluta!
          Distinctio sed placeat eos blanditiis delectus.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- Link conent-->

      <!-- Link conent-->
      <div id="link3">
        <h1>Link Three</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis,
          sequi voluptates ratione iure quidem cum tempora! Voluptate
          consequatur numquam assumenda natus eum quisquam non repudiandae
          corrupti, dignissimos omnis enim voluptatem, exercitationem
          incidunt beatae. Dignissimos eius maxime ullam rem praesentium
          iusto natus cum corporis rerum, voluptates recusandae ea
          repudiandae dicta autem ex! Repellat iusto, sit ratione suscipit
          quidem reiciendis, similique laboriosam nemo, ipsa sint sapiente
          amet itaque enim aliquam eligendi molestias tenetur at adipisci?
          Sint, blanditiis. Molestiae nobis, quam sequi sapiente id
          voluptate corrupti commodi voluptas alias distinctio nam sunt
          ipsam ad non ratione exercitationem, nihil deleniti maiores velit
          labore quibusdam reprehenderit impedit deserunt! Reiciendis nemo
          ducimus fugiat perferendis esse ut accusantium officiis, neque
          minima voluptates ipsum corrupti, quo ratione rem tempora?
          Laudantium, quidem? Dolor laudantium fuga nihil odit, autem
          asperiores iste explicabo. Officia rerum ab facilis odio explicabo
          minima maiores distinctio a cumque, mollitia beatae sunt ullam
          soluta et exercitationem est quae. Fugiat cum veniam nostrum,
          ullam laudantium porro debitis reprehenderit natus, consectetur
          qui neque labore maxime. Obcaecati repudiandae, ab cupiditate
          deleniti repellat commodi id ullam, dignissimos quidem, fugiat
          saepe dolor distinctio odit recusandae accusantium nemo. Fugit
          dolorem quibusdam laboriosam? Alias voluptatem corporis quos. Sint
          quod eos, dignissimos, tempore similique repudiandae deserunt aut
          voluptate quis nulla sequi quam fugiat impedit? Laudantium fugiat
          magnam earum amet, accusantium nostrum veritatis eum, et minima ut
          cupiditate molestias totam corporis sit suscipit cumque?
          Repudiandae commodi officia minima, nesciunt ex labore veniam quos
          libero eum porro et quibusdam facere esse earum debitis culpa
          quisquam eius quia quae eligendi? Libero, ullam esse quas quisquam
          at et provident officia similique iste porro nisi aliquid, dolor
          delectus velit. Corporis, eum corrupti. Aspernatur perspiciatis
          sed inventore vitae fugiat deleniti vero exercitationem ut ex
          assumenda nulla porro unde aperiam, ullam ipsum in non tempore
          repudiandae harum quasi dolorum. Quas sint ab voluptatum,
          praesentium, neque reiciendis voluptas quae quisquam aperiam
          quibusdam, illum iusto quo et impedit porro tenetur animi sapiente
          eligendi ipsam ad voluptate! Nesciunt quas sunt molestiae
          laboriosam? Natus quo at a officia cupiditate autem, numquam
          sapiente maxime fugiat beatae quis amet voluptates. Facere ducimus
          natus magni ipsa numquam nobis laborum quisquam itaque assumenda
          quaerat commodi vel vero dolores, accusantium, adipisci quasi
          iusto quis consectetur, eligendi asperiores inventore distinctio.
          Ut officiis molestiae dolorum, recusandae doloremque accusantium
          dignissimos atque ad omnis. Ex perspiciatis, commodi labore veniam
          eos a exercitationem deleniti eaque in quaerat corrupti atque
          tenetur voluptate, sint libero quo? Alias pariatur itaque eligendi
          voluptas tenetur, nobis eveniet, ex dolorem modi consequatur
          dolore recusandae nostrum! Alias numquam nemo perspiciatis libero,
          blanditiis in aliquid placeat quia velit iste repudiandae rem
          laborum ratione molestiae quas beatae, nulla, suscipit quos
          commodi at deleniti vel incidunt distinctio recusandae! Fugit
          voluptatum officiis mollitia necessitatibus aperiam temporibus est
          dolores atque inventore minus quam unde ipsum alias sapiente sint
          dolorem ullam, placeat commodi adipisci maxime suscipit odio
          reiciendis labore quasi. Architecto vero repudiandae voluptatum
          vel temporibus, ea omnis sapiente. Ut, eligendi doloribus error
          ullam obcaecati sint sequi. Ipsa debitis doloribus nulla soluta!
          Distinctio sed placeat eos blanditiis delectus.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- Link conent-->

      <!-- Link conent-->
      <div id="link4">
        <h1>Link Four</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis,
          sequi voluptates ratione iure quidem cum tempora! Voluptate
          consequatur numquam assumenda natus eum quisquam non repudiandae
          corrupti, dignissimos omnis enim voluptatem, exercitationem
          incidunt beatae. Dignissimos eius maxime ullam rem praesentium
          iusto natus cum corporis rerum, voluptates recusandae ea
          repudiandae dicta autem ex! Repellat iusto, sit ratione suscipit
          quidem reiciendis, similique laboriosam nemo, ipsa sint sapiente
          amet itaque enim aliquam eligendi molestias tenetur at adipisci?
          Sint, blanditiis. Molestiae nobis, quam sequi sapiente id
          voluptate corrupti commodi voluptas alias distinctio nam sunt
          ipsam ad non ratione exercitationem, nihil deleniti maiores velit
          labore quibusdam reprehenderit impedit deserunt! Reiciendis nemo
          ducimus fugiat perferendis esse ut accusantium officiis, neque
          minima voluptates ipsum corrupti, quo ratione rem tempora?
          Laudantium, quidem? Dolor laudantium fuga nihil odit, autem
          asperiores iste explicabo. Officia rerum ab facilis odio explicabo
          minima maiores distinctio a cumque, mollitia beatae sunt ullam
          soluta et exercitationem est quae. Fugiat cum veniam nostrum,
          ullam laudantium porro debitis reprehenderit natus, consectetur
          qui neque labore maxime. Obcaecati repudiandae, ab cupiditate
          deleniti repellat commodi id ullam, dignissimos quidem, fugiat
          saepe dolor distinctio odit recusandae accusantium nemo. Fugit
          dolorem quibusdam laboriosam? Alias voluptatem corporis quos. Sint
          quod eos, dignissimos, tempore similique repudiandae deserunt aut
          voluptate quis nulla sequi quam fugiat impedit? Laudantium fugiat
          magnam earum amet, accusantium nostrum veritatis eum, et minima ut
          cupiditate molestias totam corporis sit suscipit cumque?
          Repudiandae commodi officia minima, nesciunt ex labore veniam quos
          libero eum porro et quibusdam facere esse earum debitis culpa
          quisquam eius quia quae eligendi? Libero, ullam esse quas quisquam
          at et provident officia similique iste porro nisi aliquid, dolor
          delectus velit. Corporis, eum corrupti. Aspernatur perspiciatis
          sed inventore vitae fugiat deleniti vero exercitationem ut ex
          assumenda nulla porro unde aperiam, ullam ipsum in non tempore
          repudiandae harum quasi dolorum. Quas sint ab voluptatum,
          praesentium, neque reiciendis voluptas quae quisquam aperiam
          quibusdam, illum iusto quo et impedit porro tenetur animi sapiente
          eligendi ipsam ad voluptate! Nesciunt quas sunt molestiae
          laboriosam? Natus quo at a officia cupiditate autem, numquam
          sapiente maxime fugiat beatae quis amet voluptates. Facere ducimus
          natus magni ipsa numquam nobis laborum quisquam itaque assumenda
          quaerat commodi vel vero dolores, accusantium, adipisci quasi
          iusto quis consectetur, eligendi asperiores inventore distinctio.
          Ut officiis molestiae dolorum, recusandae doloremque accusantium
          dignissimos atque ad omnis. Ex perspiciatis, commodi labore veniam
          eos a exercitationem deleniti eaque in quaerat corrupti atque
          tenetur voluptate, sint libero quo? Alias pariatur itaque eligendi
          voluptas tenetur, nobis eveniet, ex dolorem modi consequatur
          dolore recusandae nostrum! Alias numquam nemo perspiciatis libero,
          blanditiis in aliquid placeat quia velit iste repudiandae rem
          laborum ratione molestiae quas beatae, nulla, suscipit quos
          commodi at deleniti vel incidunt distinctio recusandae! Fugit
          voluptatum officiis mollitia necessitatibus aperiam temporibus est
          dolores atque inventore minus quam unde ipsum alias sapiente sint
          dolorem ullam, placeat commodi adipisci maxime suscipit odio
          reiciendis labore quasi. Architecto vero repudiandae voluptatum
          vel temporibus, ea omnis sapiente. Ut, eligendi doloribus error
          ullam obcaecati sint sequi. Ipsa debitis doloribus nulla soluta!
          Distinctio sed placeat eos blanditiis delectus.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- Link conent-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```