# position sticky with a 3 rows header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a 3 rows header and I need the middle row to be sticky, I tried using `position: sticky` but since it's relative to the element's parent I'm unable to achieve the result that I want.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8sczt7u1/2/

I was going for a CSS only solution but I'm well aware that this is a very particular case so I'm open to javascript as well.

Comment: *I'm unable to achieve the result that I want.* --> and what do you want?

Comment: @TemaniAfif keep the second row sticky on scroll?

Comment: @TemaniAfif "I have a 3 rows header and I need the middle row to be sticky" isn't that clear enough?

Comment: related then: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62426596/8620333

Answer (score 3):

Just add a display inline to your header tag

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page-content {
  min-height: 200vh;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.top-bar {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  &__nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    li {
      margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    }
  }
}

.promo-bar {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="top-bar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="main-bar">
    <div class="main-bar__logo">Logo</div>
    <ul class="main-bar__nav">
      <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="promo-bar">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecur bla bla bla</div>
</header>

<div class="page-content"></div>
```

Comment: That's actually a very good hack, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @mIkeMo happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

So I fixed it by removing the wrapper around my 3 rows and using the `<header>` tag as the main row wrapper

https://jsfiddle.net/yvgLaq5f/

Answer (score -2):

Your code is working correctly. `position: sticky` operates within its container i.e. `header.

You can set the `header` `height: 500px` and see this.

Comment: I'm aware that it's working as intented, the goal was to have the middle row be sticky throughout the entire page. Thanks for suggestion though I appreciate your time.

Comment: Any code is working as intended in that case lol, but that doesn't answer his question