# Sticky header in flexbox table is not sticky

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created a flexbox based table, which is stripped to the basics the example below.

```
<!-- display: flex;flex-flow: column nowrap; flex:1 1 auto; --> 
<div class="ovdTable"> 
  <!-- display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; flex: 1 1 auto; -->
  <div class="ovdTable__table">  
    <!-- flex:1 1 auto; -->
    <div class="ovdTable__column">   
      <!-- display:flex; flex:none; -->                    
      <div class="ovdTable__cell ovdTable__cell--header"> 
      <!-- 1-n -->
      <div class="ovdTable__cell">                 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS class ovt_Table__cell--header adds the following style properties to the first cell in a column.

```
position: sticky;
position: -webkit-sticky;
top:0;
```

As expected i have search for similar stackoverflow articles and tried the solutions found there.

- [My position: sticky element isn't sticky when using flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446671/my-position-sticky-element-isnt-sticky-when-using-flexbox)

  - Checked for parent element with `overflow-x: hidden;`
  - Added `align-self: flex-start` to the sticky element.
- [Fixed element inside flexbox item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55659802/fixed-element-inside-flexbox-item)

  - Was not able to find any useful information here.

I have a CodePen example [here](https://codepen.io/poundfoolish/pen/gOrGVea).

Maybe I am totally wrong, but could i have made an error in the overflow settings?

Comment: Please keep solutions to the answer section. I'm not sure why you deleted the answer you wrote and included it in the question, but questions should not contain solutions. I would recommend undeleting your answer and marking it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it by adding an extra div inside the div with class "ovdTable" containing the header cells and making this div 'sticky' with an elevated z-index.

```
<!-- display: flex;flex-flow: column nowrap; flex:1 1 auto; --> 
<div class="ovdTable"> 
    <!-- display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; flex: 1 1 auto; -->
    <!-- position: sticky; top:0px; z-index:2; --> 
    <div class="ovdTable__tableHeader"> 
      <!-- 1-n -->
      <div class="ovdTable__tableHeader--column">Column 1</div>
    </div>
    <!-- display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; flex: 1 1 auto; -->
    <div class="ovdTable__tableContent">  
        <!-- flex:1 1 auto; -->
        <div class="ovdTable__column">   
            <!-- 1-n -->
            <div class="ovdTable__cell">                 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have updated the codepen to match the solution.