# Sticky position not working in float-based layout, but works outside float-based layout

Tags: css, css-position, sticky

I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas why I'm having problems with position:sticky inside a float-based layout, but not outside of it.

You can see a fiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/pjt0kmd7/1/

I'm using the following css for the sticky position:

```
.sticky {
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
    position: sticky;
    top: 1em;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

I've also tried removing overflow and heights on the first sticky's parents via:

```
overflow:none;
height:auto;
```

But that has not made any difference.  Anyone know why the first red box isn't sticky like the second?

**Edit** Looks like I figured it out, the sticky parent needs a height defined? https://jsfiddle.net/pjt0kmd7/4/

Comment: the sticky is defining the height so there is no room to have any sticky behavior

Comment: more examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54610362/8620333