# CSS position: sticky; bottom: 0 not sticking to bottom

Tags: css

I can't get `#up-arrow` to stick to the bottom of `.container`.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#up-arrow {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    border: 2px solid #23ADF8;
    border-radius: 23.5px;
    background-color: #23ADF8;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
}
#up-arrow:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
#up-arrow:hover img {
    filter: invert(63%) sepia(35%) saturate(5648%) hue-rotate(174deg) brightness(102%) contrast(95%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">     
  <div id="up-arrow">
    <a href="#top">
      <img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/up.svg">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is the similar question and pretty detailed answer as well. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54609208/why-bottom0-doesnt-work-with-positionsticky

Comment: Try with position absolute in #up-arrow with relative in parent. Or one suggestion try position fixed, if you are making this button for scroll to top in your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element `#up-arrow` will not stick to the bottom of the container with the current layout.

Because, `sticky` element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document, and then offset relative to its nearest scrolling ancestor and containing block (nearest block-level ancestor).

Here the element `#up-arrow` is at the top of the container, hence the element will not be able to stick to bottom on scroll.

Add some content on top of `#up-arrow` to see sticky working.

**Sample Implementation**

```css
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#up-arrow {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px solid #23ADF8;
  border-radius: 23.5px;
  background-color: #23ADF8;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}

#up-arrow:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

#up-arrow:hover img {
  filter: invert(63%) sepia(35%) saturate(5648%) hue-rotate(174deg) brightness(102%) contrast(95%);
}

#an-element {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="an-element"></div>
  <div id="up-arrow">
    <a href="#top">
      <img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/up.svg">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**OR**

use `position: relative;` parent and `position: absolute;` child

**Working Fiddle**

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

#up-arrow {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px solid #23ADF8;
  border-radius: 23.5px;
  background-color: #23ADF8;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

#up-arrow:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

#up-arrow:hover img {
  filter: invert(63%) sepia(35%) saturate(5648%) hue-rotate(174deg) brightness(102%) contrast(95%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="up-arrow">
    <a href="#top">
      <img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/up.svg">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as you haven't wrote any other content sitcky position may not work fine.
please review below stuff and you might get what you want,

```css
.container {
  height: 300vh;
  width: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#up-arrow {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px solid #23ADF8;
  border-radius: 23.5px;
  background-color: #23ADF8;
}

#up-arrow:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

#up-arrow:hover img {
  filter: invert(63%) sepia(35%) saturate(5648%) hue-rotate(174deg) brightness(102%) contrast(95%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="background: red;">Scroll</div>
  <div style="height: 300px; background: orange;"></div>
  <div class="sticky">Sticky Section</div>
  <div style="background: pink;">Scroll</div>
  <div style="height: 300px; background: green;"></div>
  <div class="sticky">Sticky Section</div>
  <div style="background: red;">Scroll</div>
  <div style="height: 300px; background: orange;"></div>
  <div class="sticky">Sticky Section</div>
  <div id="up-arrow">
    <a href="#top">
      <img src="https://mandoemedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/up.svg">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div style="background: pink;">Scroll</div>
  <div style="height: 300px; background: green;"></div>
  <div class="sticky">Sticky Section</div>
</div>
```

Note: I have made sticky at bottom position and for your understanding how bottom positioned sticky works I've also added some stuff below sticky positioned content.
Whenever content below sticky position renders position of screen will be initial(normal).

References: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp