# Why position sticky is not working if followed by position absolute element?

Tags: css, css-position, sticky

Below is the code snippet and if run it, you can see the header element does not stick. I have looked at the at following questions.
[“Position: sticky;” not Working CSS and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707076/position-sticky-not-working-css-and-html)
and [CSS: 'position: sticky' not working when 'height' is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848196/css-position-sticky-not-working-when-height-is-defined)
among many others but it did not help..

Here is my code.

```html
<body style="margin: 0">
  <div id="header" style="height: 50px;width: 100%;position: sticky;top: 0px;background-color: rgb(33, 150, 243);">
    <div>header contents</div>
    <div>header contents</div>
  </div>
  <div id="container" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 0px; width: 100%; background: #ddd;">
    <div style="height: 1000px;">
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Also I noticed if I remove position: absolute from the container div, the sticky starts to work properly. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Adding border to the body will show you the issue:

```html
<body style="margin: 0;border:2px solid red;">
  <div id="header" style="height: 50px;width: 100%;position: sticky;top: 0px;background-color: rgb(33, 150, 243);">
    <div>header contents</div>
    <div>header contents</div>
  </div>
  <div id="container" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 0px; width: 100%;">
    <div style="height: 1000px;">
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

As you can see the height of the body is defined by the sticky element thus there [is no sticky behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52997848/8620333). if you remove the `positon:absolute` you will make the element part of the flow thus the body height will increase and you have a sticky behavior

```html
<body style="margin: 0;border:2px solid red;">
  <div id="header" style="height: 50px;width: 100%;position: sticky;top: 0px;background-color: rgb(33, 150, 243);">
    <div>header contents</div>
    <div>header contents</div>
  </div>
  <div id="container" style=" top: 50px; left: 0px; width: 100%;">
    <div style="height: 1000px;">
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The issue isn't the `position:absolute` element but **the height of the containing block** (parent container) of the sticky element. This one need to be big enough (at least bigger than the sticky element) to have a sticky behavior.

Increasing the body height and keeping the absolute element will also fix this:

```html
<body style="margin: 0;border:2px solid red;height:200px;">
  <div id="header" style="height: 50px;width: 100%;position: sticky;top: 0px;background-color: rgb(33, 150, 243);">
    <div>header contents</div>
    <div>header contents</div>
  </div>
  <div id="container" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 0px; width: 100%;">
    <div style="height: 1000px;">
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

Another related answer where you can find more examples of how sticky works: [Why element with position:sticky doesn't stick to the bottom of parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54609208/8620333)

Comment: know of any questions discussing `sticky` in the context of offsetting inline elements with `translateY`?

Comment: i edited my question. what i am doing is wrapping each letter of a `p` in a `span`, then `translateY` offsetting each letter incrementally (i.e. first letter is offset by `100%`, second letter `200%`, third `300%`, and so on) and i want them to stick to the top of the container as one scrolls the element to eventually form the whole word/sentence/etc, but cant figure out how to do it

Comment: @oldboy I guess it deserve a question ;) It would be easier to make a full answer instead of simple comment (more users can also think about the issue and give potential solutions)

Comment: ok, posted a Q. i did my best to word it as well as i could. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64271747/position-sticky-while-offsetting-inline-elements) is the quesiton

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, since the body height is not set, the header's `position` will never change from `relative` to `fixed` (this is what `sticky` does - see (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

If you needed to keep the container absolutely positioned but can't/don't want to define the body height, you could use `position:fixed` instead of `position:sticky` for the header id, and include `z-index:1` so that it appears over the container:

```html
<body style="margin: 0">
  <div id="header" style="height: 50px;width: 100%;position: fixed;top: 0px;background-color: rgb(33, 150, 243); z-index:1;">
    <div>header contents</div>
    <div>header contents</div>
  </div>
  <div id="container" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 0px; width: 100%; background: #ddd;">
    <div style="height: 1000px;">
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
      <div>some contents</div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case,if you want to set height of div to specific value, you can set min-height:1000px for body element and set z-index for div#header to 1.

```
<body style="margin: 0;min-height: 1000px">
<div id="header"
     style="height: 50px;width: 100%;position: sticky;top: 0;background-color: rgb(33, 150, 243);z-index:1">
    <div>header contents</div>
    <div>header contents</div>
</div>
    <div id="container" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 0; width: 100%; background: #ddd;">
        <div style="height: 1000px;">
            <div>some contents</div>
            <br>
            <div>some contents</div>
            <br>
            <div>some contents</div>
            <br>
            <div>some contents</div>
            <br>
            <div>some contents</div>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
```