# Sticky position not working for overlapping scrolling effect

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an overlapping effect when the user scrolls using the `sticky` position and giving each `div` (section) a new background colour. However, even after setting `top` to 0 for the `sticky` position, the `divs` scroll out of the viewport. Any help would be great!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#about').click(function(){
            $('#aboutcontainer').slideToggle('slow');
        });
});
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 22px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

h3 {
 margin: 0;
}

ul, li {
 margin: 0 auto;
}

span {
 font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
 height:102vh;
}

.contentcontainer {
 display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   height: auto;
}

.vertical-center {
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#navbar {
 width: 100%;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 font-family: Abel;
 height: 100px;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper {
 padding: 0 45px;
 height: inherit;
 position: relative;
}

#logo {
 font-size: 200%;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper ul {
 margin-top: 6.5vh;
 float: right;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper li {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 25px;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #000000;
 font-family: Abel;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper li:nth-child(even):hover {
 cursor: default;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper li:nth-child(odd):hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

#aboutcontainer {
    display: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#aboutcontainer p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 45px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 80%;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 92%;
}

#one {
 background-color: #ffd700;
 position: sticky; 
 top: 0;
}

#two {
 background-color: #468499;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
}

#three {
 background-color: #468499;
 position: sticky; 
 top: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

 #logo {
  margin-top: -1vh;
 }

#desktop-nav-wrapper {
 padding: 0 15px;
 height: inherit;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper ul {
 float: left;
 padding-left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 11vh;
}

#desktop-nav-wrapper li {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 0;
 margin-right: 2%;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #000000;
 font-family: Abel;
}

#aboutcontainer p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 90%;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 80%;
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
 <div id="desktop-nav-wrapper">
     <h3 id="logo" class="vertical-center">Test Header</h3>
         <ul>
             <li id="about" class="desktop-items">about</li>
         </ul>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div id="aboutcontainer" style="display: none;">
   <p>
      Phasellus vitae semper risus. Quisque in finibus nisi. Sed non rhoncus purus, eu luctus orci. Vestibulum massa nisi, bibendum eget libero ut, tempor mattis metus. Maecenas placerat nisl non mauris fringilla ultricies. Phasellus dignissim velit vitae tellus sodales luctus. Nullam tempus turpis vitae nunc lacinia faucibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eget volutpat nunc. Cras et libero et ligula suscipit finibus et id dui. Duis odio enim, interdum vitae ullamcorper ut, sagittis vitae metus. Phasellus feugiat libero metus, sed tempor erat porttitor ut. Integer vel libero eu ante sollicitudin fermentum non quis nisl. Aliquam blandit dignissim sem, et malesuada risus venenatis eget. Nulla pretium ornare dui fermentum cursus. 
     </p>
</div>

<div class="container" id="one">
 <div class="contentcontainer">
  <h3>One</h3>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="two">
 <div class="contentcontainer">
  <h3>Two</h3>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="three">
 <div class="contentcontainer">
  <h3>Three</h3>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848196/css-position-sticky-not-working-when-height-is-defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out... Turns out `position: sticky` isn't a fan of `HTML` and `body` having their `height` set to `100%`. I removed it and it now works fine.