# position:sticky only works with height

Tags: css, responsive-design, sticky

Why do I need to define a height for position sticky?

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="contentGrid"> {# css grid element #}
    {# other stuff #}
    <div class="sideBar"> {# some stuff inside sidebar #} </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does not work:

```
.sideBar {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

Does work:

```
.sideBar {
     position: sticky;
     top: 0;
     height: 100px; // why tho?
}
```

Why is there a height needed? How can I make this relative to the content? An absolute px height will inevitabely to lead problems down the road.

Comment: Is there is any other CSS code which can add some extra styling to this element, for example float..?

Comment: I found some interesting post to read.. Can be useful in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848196/position-sticky-not-working-when-height-is-defined

Comment: @MarioBoss No floats. just flexbox & css grid

Comment: Without seeing more of your layout and CSS it's impossible to debug but the short answer to why you need to define height is that you don't and something else is happening.

Comment: Actually, if your sideBar div is empty then yes... nothing will render there but that is the same with all block level elements, they have no inherent height.

Comment: dangit. then the problem lies somewhere else. `position:sticky` is so hard.

Comment: you said you have flexbox so for sure your element is having a full height of its parent due to the  stretch effect. Add border to the sticky element and to the parent element to notice this. Let me know if what I said is true so I can redirect you to the correct duplicate

Comment: @TemaniAfif YES. The sticky element is stretched to it's parent. `align-self: flex-start;` and the whole thing works  webdesign is hard

Comment: I added 3 relevant duplicates so you can better understand your issue and how sticky works