# Scrolling effect - Make components stack on top of each other when scrolling CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I've been trying to achieve this scrolling effect from this website: https://livingbeautyinc.com. As you scroll, the previous content stays on the same position and the new content stacks on top of the old one. I've tried using the `position:sticky` then set the `z-index` for each component but it doesn't seem to work. Anyone has any idea how to make this scrolling effect with CSS?

Source: https://codepen.io/daniel5120/pen/PoEoaEP
So ideally I want to make the contents on the first container stay exactly the same where they are and then the second element stays on top of the first one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code on `codepen` did not work with  `position: sticky` due to the height in `html` and `body`. If you want to learn more, [I think this is the explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49852675/4031083)

[Here is your modified `codepen` code.](https://codepen.io/baro82/pen/xxpxJRv)

And below is an example I did to help me understand why your code didn't work.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.pages {
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
        top: 0;
    
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="pages" style="background-color:red;">
    <h1>Title RED</h1>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/100?random=1">
</div>

<div class="pages" style="background-color:yellow;">
    <h1>Title YELLOW</h1>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/100?random=2">
</div>

<div class="pages" style="background-color:blue;">
    <h1>Title BLUE</h1>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/100?random=3">
</div>

<div class="pages" style="background-color:green;">
    <h1>Title GREEN</h1>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/100?random=4">
</div>
```